# Why is my program not debugging on vscode (c#) like it used to? I am being asked to attach to a process

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-code

[Disclaimer: very new to coding]

I am learning to code and have so far covered some basic tutorials and can produce simple programs. These all used to run fine.

For some reason I can't explain, I am now running into an error every time I am trying to "start debugging".

For example, when trying to debug the default "Hello World!" code (as below),

```
using System;

namespace specialitySelector
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

A drop down list appears (as below) and the program does not run! I have no idea why this is doing this :/.

[Image of drop down list that appears and what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGoK6.png)

In my launch.json file I have this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            // Use IntelliSense to find out which attributes exist for C# debugging
            // Use hover for the description of the existing attributes
            // For further information visit https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/net5.0/specialitySelector.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            // For more information about the 'console' field, see https://aka.ms/VSCode-CS-LaunchJson-Console
            "console": "externalTerminal",
            "stopAtEntry": false
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach"
        }
    ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this? I have even tried uninstalling and re-installing vscode with no result.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't seem to have actually supplied the image.

Comment: Apologies. I think the image should now be linked.

Comment: Have you installed a version of the .NET framework like .NET core?

Comment: Yes. I have installed .NET core